# NASM extern symbols with leading $

Tags: assembly, nasm, symbols

The NASM documentation states:

> The only characters which may be used as the first character of an identifier are letters, . (with special meaning: see section 3.9), _ and ?.

I need to call an external procedure whose symbol starts with a leading `$`. Sadly the docs do not specify how to escape the $ or how to deal with the restriction.

Does anyone know how to specify an external symbol with a leading dollar sign?

Comment: I think you can put some sort of quotes around the symbol name.  Have you checked the NASM manual?

Comment: @fuz I've been referring to the manual; and no, I couldn't find anything regarding this. I tried using ", ', `. I must admit, that I am still learning to write x86_64 assembly with NASM.

Comment: You might have to work around NASM, possibly with another object file that defines aliases for your `$` symbols, like maybe GAS using `.weakref` or `.ref`?  I'm not sure how exactly aliases work and if that's possible.  Or you could just use GAS, which lets you use `mov "$foo"(%rip), %eax` to quote the $ so it's part of the symbol name, instead of indicating an immediate in AT&T syntax.  Or in `.intel_syntax noprefix`, `mov eax, [rip + $foo]` might not even need quotes.

Comment: @JulianKirsch Hm... in this case I believe it is not possible.

Comment: Note that `mov eax, [$foo]` assembles, but `objdump -drwC` shows that it references the symbol `foo` not `$foo`.  Doubling the `$` to `$$foo` makes it a syntax error.  (In NASM, a leading `$` disambiguates symbol names vs. register names, like `$eax` is a symbol with that name.)

Comment: Would this work for you? `ld --defsym=nasm.foo=$foo`

Comment: @prl that would work for me. Do you perhaps know how to wrap that in a linker script; I'd accept that as an answer? I am still fighting with `ld`.

Comment: In a linker script, I think you can just write `nasm.foo = $foo;`.

Answer (score 2):

> I need to call an external procedure whose symbol starts with a leading `$`.
> Sadly the docs do not specify how to escape the $ or how to deal with the restriction.

The documentation does not explain that because it is not possible.
The [`extern` directive](https://github.com/netwide-assembler/nasm/blob/nasm-2.15.xx/asm/directiv.c#L297-L299) will always ignore a leading `$` (there is no ambiguity between register `rax` vs. label `rax`, since a register cannot be used in a label declaration).
The first actual character of any identifier must be [categorized as `NCT_IDSTART`](https://github.com/netwide-assembler/nasm/blob/nasm-2.15.xx/nasmlib/nctype.c#L65-L110), otherwise it is invalid.